# How do I read comma separated doubles from text file into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv, textscan

I have a text file called Output.txt that looks like this:

```
0.000000,0.550147,0.884956
1.000000,0.532486,0.847458
2.000000,0.501333,0.800000
3.000000,0.466418,0.746269
4.000000,0.409492,0.662252
5.000000,0.327257,0.520833
6.000000,0.267376,0.425532
7.000000,0.188427,0.296736
8.000000,0.115824,0.180505
9.000000,0.062768,0.099108
```

I need to read in the three values separated by commas into MATLAB as 3 different vectors. They can be called anything but `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` could work.

`C1` would contain `[0.000000,1.000000,2.000000, ...]`, `C2` would contain `[0.550147,0.532486,...]` and `C3` would contain the values in the third column `[0.884956,0.847458,...]`.

I tried using the following but I'm having problems getting it to work correctly:

```
File = 'Output.txt';
f = fopen(File, 'r');
C = textscan(f, '%f%f%f', 'Delimiter', ',');
fclose(f);
```

This gives me a 1x3 Cell array `C` but each of the cells in `C` are 1x100 and do not contain the correct numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `Comma Separated Value` file, so you can simply use [`csvread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) to read in your matrix:

```
C = csvread('Output.txt');
```

where `C` now is a matrix containing all your values, which you can of course index through columns and rows. I'd recommend against creating the column vectors rather use `C(:,1)` for the first column etc.

Comment: I have tried this previously and it did not work as you have explained. I know that I have a comma separated value file but when I use csvread it gives me a 1x100 vector. I think there might be a problem with the decimal values of my file.

Comment: with the file you present this works for me. Can you please post a [mcve] which outlines why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I figured out my problem, Matlab was having a problem finding my file on my computer. I used an exact path to my file inside the csvread(path/to/my/file) command and it worked. Thanks.